# How many functions $f: B\to B$ map even numbers to even numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, proof-verification

> How many functions $f: B\to B$ map even numbers to even numbers if $B=\{5,2,7,4,9,6\}$?

Because there's a requirement to map even numbers to even numbers then the domain and the range of $f$ is $B'=\{2,4,6\}$ as far as I understand. Then the number of possible functions is $|B'|^{|B'|}=3^3$.

Not sure regarding the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition to be satisfied for $f:B\to B$ (so the domain is $B$ and not $B'$) is that $f(B')\subseteq B'$. Since there are no constraints on the image of odd numbers, the number of such functions should be
$$\underbrace{|B|^{|B|-|B'|}}_{\text{image of odd numbers}}\cdot \underbrace{|B'|^{|B'|}}_{\text{image of even numbers}}=6^3\cdot 3^3.$$

Comment: does the $|B|^{|B|-|B'|}$ part refer to functions where both odd and even numbers map to even numbers?

Comment: No, this is the part where odd numbers  $(|B|-|B'|)$ map to both odd and even numbers $(|B|)$.

Comment: If I were to count the number of injective functions with the same constraint would it be $6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3!$? (where $6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ refers to odd functions and $3!$ refers to functions between even numbers)

Comment: No. Injective is the same of bijective here. So odd map to odd and even map to even: $3!\cdot 3!$

Comment: But why? the first odd number can be paired up with 6 numbers, the second odd number can be paired with 5 and the last odd number can be paired with 4. Why is the image here different compared to the original question?

Comment: You are saying that $f(5)$ can assume $6$ possible values. Give me an example of an injective function $f:B\to B$ that maps even to even and such that $f(5)=2$ .

Comment: I think I understand now: if the function is injective then even numbers map to even numbers and odd numbers map to only odd numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That is the number of ways to choose $f(2),f(4),f(6)$. But you need functions which are defined on the whole of $B$, so you still need to choose $f(5),f(7),f(9)$. Each of these can be anything in $B$, so there are $3^3\times 6^3$ ways in total.